# Powershell how can I output results into multiple files at the same time?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Is there a way that I can `out-file` to multiple files in one shot?

something like

`{script block} | out-file $file1, $file2, $file3`

I want to keep few copies of the same results.

I tested few ways, nothing worked.

Comment: No, you will need to create a collection of files, then loop through them to output to each of them

Comment: Pretty sure `Add-Content` and `Set-Content` do this `[-Path] <string[]>`. Why not try them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Out-File` cannot do this

---

However, [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) do support this for their `-Path` parameters

An example, from the links above, for `Set-Content` has a similar example for this as well using wildcards.

> ```
> PS> Get-ChildItem -Path .\Test*.txt
>
> Test1.txt
> Test2.txt
> Test3.txt
>
> PS> Set-Content -Path .\Test*.txt -Value 'Hello, World'
>
> PS> Get-Content -Path .\Test*.txt
>
> Hello, World
> Hello, World
> Hello, World
> ```

But, `-Path` supports arrays so you just need to change the cmdlet you are using and should be off to the races.

```
{script block} | Set-Content -Path $file1, $file2, $file3
```

Comment: Good to know this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be one-shot? [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object?view=powershell-5.0) is built to pass the pipeline straight through it and out the other side, while saving it to a file as well. It has the default alias `tee` so you could:

```
{script block} |tee $file1 |tee $file2 |tee $file3
```